# Why does std::declval add a reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, decltype, declval

[`std::declval`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) is a compile-time utility used to construct an expression for the purpose of determining its type. It is defined like this:

```
template< class T >
typename std::add_rvalue_reference<T>::type declval() noexcept;
```

Would this not be simpler instead?

```
template< class T >
T declval() noexcept;
```

What is the advantage of a reference return type? And shouldn't it be called `declref`?

The earliest historical example I find is [n2958](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2958.html#Value), which calls the function `value()` but already always returns a reference.

Note, the operand of `decltype` does not need to have an accessible destructor, i.e. it is not semantically checked as a full-expression.

```
template< typename t >
t declprval() noexcept;

class c { ~ c (); };
decltype ( declprval< c >() ) * p = nullptr; // OK
```

Comment: Doesn't `T` need to be copyable for `T` to be a valid return type? `T &&` would avoid that.

Comment: I think it's to support types that can't be return by value, e.g. function type, array type, and abstract class.

Comment: @user2357112: Movability is sufficient.

Comment: @Mehrdad Any class type may be a return type, movability is unnecessary.

Comment: @jrok My example also does not require constructibility.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I never said movability is necessary.

Comment: @Mehrdad Technically true, but…

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The "no temporary is introduced for function returning prvalue of object type in `decltype`" rule applies only if the function call itself is either the operand of `decltype` or the right operand of a comma operator that's the operand of `decltype` (§5.2.2 [expr.call]/p11), which means that given `declprval` in the OP,

```
template< typename t >
t declprval() noexcept;

class c { ~ c (); };

int f(c &&);

decltype(f(declprval<c>())) i;  // error: inaccessible destructor
```

doesn't compile. More generally, returning `T` would prevent most non-trivial uses of `declval` with incomplete types, type with private destructors, and the like:

```
class D;

int f(D &&);

decltype(f(declprval<D>())) i2;  // doesn't compile. D must be a complete type
```

and doing so has little benefit since xvalues are pretty much indistinguishable from prvalues except when you use `decltype` on them, and you don't usually use `decltype` directly on the return value of `declval` - you know the type already.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize the unchecked destructor was a special exception. My example was totally misguided.

Comment: _"no temporary is introduced for function returning prvalue of object type in decltype"_ **turns into** _"If expression is a prvalue other than a (possibly parenthesized) immediate invocation (since C++20), a temporary object is not materialized from that prvalue."_ **since c++17**. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype

Answer (score 12):

Arrays cannot be returned by value thus even just the declaration of a function returning an array by value is invalid code.

You can however return an array by reference.

Comment: That's not true, T doesn't have to be copyable or moveable, it even can be incomplete, see http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f387e9e4e0ce190

Comment: @Jamboree: using `typedef int A[4]` is going to make `A f();` invalid code.

Comment: I can't see what this has got to do with `declval`.

Comment: @jrok: a definition of `declval` based on a function returning `T` by value couldn't be used when `T` is an array.

Comment: I know. But I don't know why you'd ever want to use declval with array types (may just be my lack of imagination).

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of `decltype()` is to have an expression that acts as a valid value of type `T`, to put it as a `T` in expressions expecting `T`s. The problem is that in C++ a type `T`can be non-copyable, or even non-default-constructible. So using the `T{}` for that purpose doesn't work.

What `decltype()` does is to return an rvalue-reference to a `T`. An rvalue reference should be valid for any type `T`, so its guaranteed that we have a valid `T` from an rvalue reference of `T`, and its guaranteed we can have an rvalue reference to any type `T`. Thats the trick.

Think about `decltype()` as "*give me a valid expression of type `T`*". Of course its usage is intended for overload resolution, type determination, etc; since its purpose is to return a *valid expression* (In the syntactical sense), not to return a value. Thats reflected in the fact that `std::declval()` is not defined at all, its only declared.
If it was defined, we have the initial problem again (We have to construct a value for an arbitrary type `T`, and thats not possible).

Comment: 1. I didn't propose to use `T{}`. 2. `decltype` returns an rvalue or lvalue reference.