# Is std::declval outdated because of guaranteed copy elision?

Tags: c++, c++17, copy-elision, return-value-optimization, declval

The standard library utility `declval` is [defined](http://wg21.link/declval) as:

```cpp
template<class T> add_rvalue_reference_t<T> declval() noexcept;
```

To add a *rvalue reference* here seemed like a good idea, if you think about the language when it was introduced in *C++11*: Returning a value involved a temporary, that was subsequently moved from.
Now *C++17* introduced *guaranteed copy elision* and this does not apply any more. As [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) puts it:

> C++17 core language specification of prvalues and temporaries is
> fundamentally different from that of the earlier C++ revisions: there
> is no longer a temporary to copy/move from. Another way to describe
> C++17 mechanics is "unmaterialized value passing": prvalues are
> returned and used without ever materializing a temporary.

This has some consequences on other utilities implemented in terms of `declval`. Have a look at this example (view on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/YTTv36ndv)):

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

struct Class {
    explicit Class() noexcept {}    
    Class& operator=(Class&&) noexcept = delete;
};

Class getClass() {
    return Class();
}

void test() noexcept {
    Class c{getClass()}; // succeeds in C++17 because of guaranteed copy elision
}

static_assert(std::is_constructible<Class, Class>::value); // fails because move ctor is deleted
```

Here we have a *nonmovable* class. Because of *guaranteed copy elision*, it can be returned from a function and then locally materialised in `test()`. However the `is_construtible` type trait suggests this is not possible, because it is [defined](http://wg21.link/meta.unary.prop#8) in terms of `declval`:

> The predicate condition for a template specialization
> `is_­constructible<T, Args...>` shall be satisfied if and only if the
> following variable definition would be well-formed for some invented
> variable `t`:
> `T t(declval<Args>()...);`

So in our example, the type trait states if `Class` can be constructed from a hypothetical function that returns `Class&&`. Whether the the line in `test()` is allowed cannot be predicted by any of the current type traits, despite the naming suggests that `is_constructible` does.

This means, in all situations where *guaranteed copy elision* would actually save the day, `is_constructible` misleads us by telling us the answer to "Would it be constructible *in C++11*?".

This is not limited to `is_constructible`. Extend the example above with (view on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/dzbvjW3Ms))

```cpp
void consume(Class) noexcept {}

void test2() {
    consume(getClass()); // succeeds in C++17 because of guaranteed copy elision
}

static_assert(std::is_invocable<decltype(consume), Class>::value); // fails because move ctor is deleted
```

This shows that `is_invocable` is similarly affected.

The most straightforward solution to this would be to change `declval` to

```cpp
template<class T> T declval_cpp17() noexcept;
```

Is this a defect in the C++17 (and subsequent, i.e. C++20) standard? Or am I missing a point why these `declval`,  `is_constructible` and `is_invocable` specifications are still the best solution we can have?

Comment: very related/maybe dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303250/is-there-a-reason-declval-returns-add-rvalue-reference-instead-of-add-lvalue-ref.  Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707441/why-does-stddeclval-add-a-reference

Comment: `Class c2(c1);` fails. Why should `is_constructible` say it doesn't? In your example you're not constructing a new object at all.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili `Class c2(c1)` is trying to construct from `Class&` (or `Class const&`). And this would be denied correctly by `is_constructible`

Comment: @Tobi Type of `c1` is `Class`, not `Class&`.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili, the type of the variable `c1` is. But the type of the expression is a reference.

Comment: @Tobi no, that's not right. Type of an expression cannot be a reference. http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-1

Comment: @NathanOliver These are pre-C++17

Answer (score 6):

> However the `is_construtible` type trait suggests this is not possible, because it is defined in terms of `declval`:

`Class` is not *constructible* from an instance of its own type. So `is_constructible` should not say that it is.

If a type `T` satisfies `is_constructible<T, T>`, the expectation is that you can make a `T` given an object of type `T`, *not* that you can make a `T` specifically from a prvalue of type `T`. This is not a quirk of using `declval`; it is what the question `is_constructible` means.

What you're suggesting is that `is_constructible` should answer a different question than the one it is intended to answer. And it should be noted, guaranteed elision means that *all types* are "constructible" from a prvalue of its own type. So if that was what you wanted to ask, you already have the answer.

Comment: The "*all types* are constructible" is quite convincing in your answer... But for the preceding paragraph: Why shouldn't `is_constructible<T,T>` mean from prvalue here, we already have `is_constructible<T,T&>` and `is_constructible<T,T const&>` to denote "construct from a given object". And how would that argument generalize to `is_invocable`?

Comment: @Tobi: I think the way to think about it is that use of a prvalue to initialize something is not *construction* at all.

Comment: @Tobi: "*Why shouldn't `is_constructible<T,T>` mean from prvalue here*" Because there's no such thing as a prvalue *type*. Expressions are prvalues, but types are not.

Comment: IMO declval should best approximate the inversion of decltype. And given a prvalue to decltype, it gives the type of the expression "T", which has _no_ rvalue references around. IMO this is a quirk of declval. And IMO this is independent of is_constructible. `is_same_v<T, decltype(declval<T>())>` looks desirable.

Comment: @David And though it's independent from the ideal behavior of `declval`, why should `string s(10)` not be described to "construct" a string? Isn't it even the case that a _constructor_ is called?

Comment: _And it should be noted, guaranteed elision means that all types are "constructible" from a prvalue of its own type._ I think this is an excellent example for what is wrong here. Why not make it just intuitively work? If I wanted to test against xvalue constructibility, I could pass `T&&`. If I wanted to test for prvalue constructibility, I would pass `T`.

Comment: As another answer noted, all this is probably for forwarding consistency. When I view it in that context, it all makes sense. Forwarding prvalues as prvalues is not possible. But IMO other attempts at explaining why something may not be "constructible" from a prvalue are not convincing.

Comment: What if you wanted to ask if `struct X { X(Class); };` is constructible from a prvalue of type `Class`? It certainly isn't constructible from an xvalue of type `Class`

Comment: @Artyer: Why would you want to ask if a type is constructible *specifically* from a prvalue?

Answer (score 1):

The `std::declval` function is primarily meant for forwarding. Here's an example:

```
template<typename... Ts>
auto f(Ts&&... args) -> decltype(g(std::declval<Ts>()...)) {
    return g(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

In that common case, having `std::declval` returning a prvalue is wrong, since there's no good way to forward a prvalue.

Comment: Seeing it in that context makes sense to me. Though why not write `std::forward` in the return type? `args` is visible here. Feel it needs a better example.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Yeah I came up with a simple example that shows forwarding. A more useful example of `std::forward` would be inside type traits and other places where you don't have `args...`

Answer (score 0):

In C++23, with the addition of [`std::reference_converts_from_temporary`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/reference_converts_from_temporary)/[`std::reference_constructs_from_temporary`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/reference_constructs_from_temporary), there is now precedence for `T` being a prvalue, `T&` being an lvalue and `T&&` being an xvalue in a type trait.

It is defined in the standard in terms of [`VAL<T>`](https://eel.is/c++draft/meta.unary.prop#5.sentence-1), which is basically `declval<T>()` if `T` is a reference type, otherwise a prvalue of type `T`.

This `VAL<T>` is very similar `declval_cpp17<T>()`. It would be useful in the examples you've mentioned.

However, the definition of `std::is_constructible_v` can never be changed to whether `T t(VAL<Args>...);` compiles. Too many existing call sites that look something like:

```cpp
template<typename... Args> requires(std::is_constructible_v<T, Args...>)
void construct(Args&&... args);
```

Which would have to be changed to `is_constructible_v<T, Args&&...>` to be correct.

I believe `add_rvalue_reference_t` exists in `declval` since it's meant to be used with perfect forwarding. I.e., `std::forward<T>(expr)` would have the same type and value category as `std::declval<T>()`. This should have been `std::declval<T&&>()` all along, but it can't be changed now.