# Is there a way to get the type of a dereferenced value from a dereference-able type?

Tags: c++, c++20, type-traits, c++-concepts

I'm playing around with C++ concepts and came across an interesting problem. I have the following two custom-defined concepts:

```
template<typename T>
concept is_dereferencable = requires (T t) { *t; };

template<typename T>
concept is_printable = requires (T t) { std::cout << t; };
```

As the names suggest, the first one is used to determine if a given type can be dereferenced, while the other one to check if a type supports output operator. I also have a function template called `println`, which looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
void println(const T& t)
{
    if constexpr (is_dereferencable<T>) {
        if constexpr (is_printable<decltype(*t)>) {
            std::cout << *t << '\n';
        }
    } else if constexpr (is_printable<T>) {
        std::cout << t << '\n';
    }
}
```

This prints the dereferenced value `*t` if and only if type `T` is dereference-able and the type of the dereferenced value is printable. So, for example, I can use this function template with something like an std::optional:

```
int main
{
    std::optional<std::string> stringOpt {"My Optional String"};
    ::println(stringOpt);

    return 0;
}
```

This will print `My Optional String` as expected. While this is nice, the function will just silently print nothing if the type of a dereferenced value of a derefernce-able is not printable. So, for a user-defined type `Person`, the following will just print nothing:

```
struct Person
{
    std::string m_name;
    explicit Person(const std::string& name) : m_name {name} {}
};

int main
{
    std::optional<Person> personOpt {"John Doe"}
    ::println(personOpt);
    return 0;
}
```

So I would like to move the above compile-time `if`s to a `requires` clause itself in order to get compile time errors in such cases. Is there a way to achieve that? Is there a way to get the dereferenced type of a given template type `T`? To make it a bit clearer, I would like to have something like this:

```
template<typename T>
requires is_dereferencable<T> && is_printable<decltype(*T)>
void printDereferencable(const T& t)
{
    std::cout << *t << '\n';
}
```

**P.S.:** I understand that I could remove the nested `if` and just fail upon trying to call an output operator on something that doesn't support it. However, I want to specifically move this compile-time error to the concept to get a clearer error message.

Comment: Why not `if constexpr (is_dereferencable<T>) { static_assert(is_printable<decltype(*t)>, "nice message here"); std::cout << *t << '\n'; }`?

Comment: You take a `T const&` and call `operator *()` on it. No dereference [needs to] happen. It's just a member function call. (Which might happen to work on optional, and smart pointers. You're better off making overload of a non-templated function, in my experience)
EDIT: phrasing.

Comment: @chi This would work pretty well, good point. I would still like to know if something like that would be possible though.

Comment: @viraltaco_ It also works on raw pointers and iterators. Regardless, that's not the point and is not so relevant for the question.

Comment: @hidayat-rzayev I'm not sure if it's relevant, because I'm not sure it's valid given [temp.constr.atomic-3](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.constr#temp.constr.atomic-3) since it's not a constant expression. `std::cout` is a global variable, not a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

another option is put the constraint *after* parameters, so it has access to them.

```
template<typename T>
void printDereferencable(const T& t)
requires is_dereferencable<const T&> && is_printable<decltype(*t)>
{
    std::cout << *t << '\n';
}
```

---

note: it should test on `const T&`, not `T`

Comment: Didn't know that was an acceptable syntax :o

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`std::declval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval)

```
template<typename T>
requires is_dereferencable<const T&> && is_printable<decltype(*std::declval<const T&>())>
void printDereferencable(const T& t)
{
    std::cout << *t << '\n';
}
```

---

or you can just write a `is_dereference_printable` concept

```
template<typename T>
concept is_dereference_printable = requires (T t) { std::cout << *t; };
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Great to know about `std::declval` :) Thank you!

Comment: @HidayatRzayev `std::declval()` is needed to support non-default-constructible types. Otherwise you might use just `decltype(*T())`.

Comment: Technically, `std::declval()` is used incorrectly here. `*t` in `std::cout << *t` is called on `const T`, but in `*declval<T>()` it's called on `T`. For some [weird types](https://godbolt.org/z/Parh1hcxP), these could be completely different operators.

Comment: @Evg good point, it may need to be cast to `const T&`

Comment: `*std::declval<const T&>()` should work. In generic code we should also take into account possibility to overload on `&` and `&&` ref qualifiers.

Comment: @Evg and it should also apply to all constraint parameter, or it would fail for some other weird type https://godbolt.org/z/vx1WG8aqY

Comment: fwiw, I was under the impression `declval` return a value, well obviously it's not the case here.

Comment: It always returns a some kind of a reference - to return a value you have to construct it, which you can't do for non-default-constructible types.

Comment: @Evg I believe unevaluated function (like usage of `declval`) doesn't have that constraint.

Comment: Even in unevaluated context like `decltype` you [can't](https://godbolt.org/z/evPjvrG93) default-construct a non-default-constructible type. The main purpose of `std::declval()`, which returns a reference instead of a value, is to [solve](https://godbolt.org/z/TYvjGeWr8) that problem.

Comment: @Evg that's true, well, but my point is `declval` *can* be declared to return value (or `T`) https://godbolt.org/z/99f39q4s4

Comment: For my example, that's true. But for general `T` we [can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707441/why-does-stddeclval-add-a-reference) do it.